# Second-order equation for the resistance of a filament lamp

Tags: electricity, temperature, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I am trying to determine the initial resistance $ R_0 $ of a tungsten filament in a filament lamp, by quadratic approximation of the resistance
$R(T) = R_0[1 + \alpha*T + \beta*T^2]$
but I can't find such an equation. In the laboratory I only managed to record values of Voltage, Intensity and an emission spectrum, with which, using Wien's Law, I can obtain the temperature for each wavelength.I would appreciate if you could guide me, since I would like to find this formula but also manage to determine its emissivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional form you have should be fine for the approximation of the resistance as a function of Temp.

If you recorded voltage and intensity you have "enough" to get a rough estimate of the resistance values your data set will produce.

Using that pseudo-data then you could try fitting the Resistance vs Temp curve produced by using Ohm's law ( determines resistance ), and Wein's displacement law (the corresponding Temps) to the quadratic form you have given.

As far as the emissivity goes just doing some dimensional analysis work would prob be the best bet since you may not be able to determine an exact functional relationship between the Resistance and Emissivity?

Comment: I have a question: How can I obtain the resistance value for each intensity and voltage? If I use Ohm's law, wouldn't I already be using the linear approximation? Which I don't want, since this is not an ohmic material.

Comment: Use ohms law as an estimate to generate the resistance data. The intensity will take a little working to make viable but a dimensional analysis relating intensity to current should be useful. Beyond that it is kind of a shot in the dark, if all else fails list it in your commentary on sources of error and be generous with your tolerance values?

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: No problem brother! We are all in this together after all!